# Sway input, how to get the 'us intl' layout (US keyboard international variant)

Tags: keyboard, manjaro, keyboard-layout, wayland, sway

I am trying to get this layout working
Should I put something in `/etc/sway/inputs/default-keyboard` ?

I tried to get the information with `man 5 sway-input` and `swaymsg -t get_inputs` but it did not help.
I am not even sure which configuration file the doc refers to.
I am tired of wasting my time on this issue and would really love some help

EDIT: My solution, even if I accepted the answer one that helped me the most:

In the file `/etc/sway/inputs/default-keyboard`

Add the following block

```
input type:keyboard {
    xkb_layout us
    xkb_variant intl
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file referenced by [man 5 sway-input](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sway-input.5) is the sway configuration file in `~/.config/sway/config` or `~/.sway/config` [or other allowed locations](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sway.1#CONFIGURATION). You can find the default configuration in `/etc/sway/config`.

To set your chosen layout(s) it should be enough to add something similar to this in the configuration:

```
input type:keyboard {
  xkb_layout fr,us # two layouts
  xkb_variant oss,intl # their respective variants
  xkb_options grp:sclk_toggle # toggle between layouts with the scroll-lock button
  xkb_numlock enabled # enable numlock when logging in
}
```

You can find the codes for all layouts, variants and toggle keys listed in `man xkeyboard-config`.

Answer (score 1):

Which distro are you using? At least on Debian-based distros, the keyboard is controlled by `/etc/default/keyboard`.

See the `keyboard(5)` man page for more information: [Link](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/keyboard.5.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I use manjaro a community edition with wayland and sway. It was a very bad choice. Apparently here it is in /etc/sway/inputs/default-keyboard

Comment: I couldn t find a solution in the doc