# Trying to set layout US with INTL on wayland/sway combo

Tags: manjaro, keyboard-layout, wayland, sway

I am desperate, I have spent way too much time trying to figure that out
I have manjaro CE with sway/wayland

In my /etc/sway/inputs/default-keyboard I added this

```
input type:keyboard {
    xkb_layout "us"
    xkb_variant "altgr-intl"
}
```

It does not work

Also, when I modify something in my conf, I kill the sway process to see if my modification had any effect.
Should it be enough?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702157/sway-input-how-to-get-the-us-intl-layout-us-keyboard-international-variant